# Adding the InkPicture control closes Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a Microsoft InkPicture Controll to a form. I can add it to my toolbox with no problem. However, when I add this control to the Excel form, it immediately closes. I am not able to write a single line of code related to this control. I tried to do it in Excel 2016 and Excel 365. Unfortunately, each time adding a control ends with closing the alias. Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior in Excel?

Comment: Successfully tested adding and then using InkPicture control on a UserForm just now ... Excel 365 64 bit, Windows 10. Could it be something to do with your security / Trust Center settings, or possibly your AV settings?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to do with security settings here. I have many files with very extensive macros and I have no problems with it. As for my configuration, the first attempt was made in Microsoft® Excel® 2016 MSO (version 2307 build 16.0.16626.20170) 32-bit in Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. The second attempt was in Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2307 build 16.0.16626.20170) 64 bit on Windows 11 Pro 64 bit. Excel always behaves the same in both cases. As soon as the control is placed on the form, it closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have Rubberduck installed? Probably yes. And that's exactly what's causing your problem. Try adding InkPicture Controll in Excel where you won't have Rubberduck installed. Set any properties for this control (size, position, etc.) and save the file. Then open it in Excel where you have Rubberduck installed. Your program will work fine as long as you don't change any properties of the InkPicture control.

Comment: That's exactly what was causing it! After uninstalling Rubberduck everything started working normally. Thank you for your help.